# i can not connect via VNC : timed out waiting for a response from the computer

Tags: vnc, vnc-viewer

i subscribe to a Dedicated Server Plan in Macincloud they sent me all access infos in a mail 
i follow all steps but i can not connect :/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5XZA.png)

error : timed out waiting for a response from the computer